# Materialize.css | spacing, identation and 'overriding' of span

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm using http://materializecss.com/ for my project and am fairly new to it.

Long Texts in my sidebar cause big spaces between line breaks and strange indents. How to resolve this with css?
Here's a codepen for better understanding of the issue:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVYqjx

Tried modding this so far

```
.side-nav li > a {
float: left;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

Also I couldn't reconstruct the following issue of overwritten texts
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the kind of answer you are looking for or if this will fit your need, but you can do this :

```
<span class="truncate">A lot of Stuff and other StuffnThings</span>
```

The `class="truncate"` from materializecss will hide the overflowing content, thus preventing it from overwritting text underneath or causing big spaces.